# C++ static prototype declaration in header file

Tags: c++, header, pcap

Here's my code:

```
void got_Packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet);
//in home.h

void got_Packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet){

}
//in home.cpp

pcap_loop(handle, -1, got_Packet, NULL);
//in home.cpp
```

This is the error I got.

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function
pcap_loop(handle, -1, got_Packet, NULL);
                                      ^"
```

I added syntax `static`

- on all three of them, error still occurred
- on only the prototype and the declaration, error still occurred
- on only the prototype, error is gone, MAGICALLY

Could anyone kindly enlighten me on this issue? Why must I only add the syntax `static` in the home.h  function prototype, but not in the home.cpp function declaration and calling?

Comment: Read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   and change please EDIT your question

Comment: Yep, you've removed so much context around the declaration and the error site that a good answer is unlikely.

Comment: @Useless Sorry, could you please explain more?

Comment: The error is related to either the declaration of `got_Packet`, or of `pcap_loop`, but you haven't shown any context around them. Are they class methods? Free functions? I can't tell, and this is relevant to your question. Look at Sniper's link, write the smallest standalone program that reproduces the error, and show the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Inside a class definition, the keyword static declares members that are not bound to class instances.
>   Outside a class definition, it has a different meaning: see storage duration.

[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

If your intention is to make that method static, then the correct way to do that is to declare it that way within the class definition. Static methods cannot access data specific to an instance of the class.

Comment: Do you mean if I declare `int age` in home.h, I won't be able to use variable `age` in my `static void gotPacket()` function in home.cpp?

Comment: I'm not clear on whether these declarations are part of a class definition or not. Your original post showed that at least one of the functions (got_packet I think) was part of Home (Home::got_packet). The comments on your question are asking you to clarify this. If your methods are part of a class (vs. global or namespace scope), that is definitely something we need to know.